# Detect Face Side using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, face-detection

I am working on a project which needs to detect left and right face turn in face recognition. I dont even know whether API's are available even to detect it.

I am able to detect face using OpenCV, but when I turn my face it is not even detecting the face.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Comment: Check this link http://www.cognotics.com/opencv/servo_2007_series/part_3/index.html I think this will help

Answer (score 2):

It's called profile in OpenCV and is already part of OpenCV. I guess you must use another classifier for this type of detection

Take a look at these links:

- http://alereimondo.no-ip.org/OpenCV/34
- http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/78936

Comment: Note however that profile Haar detectors have a much lower yield than the straight ones, due to the differences in the hair-styles, colors, profiles and the huge background noise at the contour.