# How to detect front and side view of human face using opencv?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, video-processing

I am working on a real time video processing project(c/c++) which needs some amount of side and frontal face detection. Frontal face detection was wasy with opencv. Is there anyway I can do it for the side view??

Comment: By side view do you mean the facial profile ? There is a ready haarcascade_profileface.xml to use. But (one of) the problem(s) with using ready things just because they are there, is when you get bad results and don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First go to [Opencv-Face Detection](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection) , see the already existing code and follow the instructions to run the code.... Now you can detect frontal face, for face profile go to [Trained Classifiers](http://alereimondo.no-ip.org/OpenCV/34) and get the trained casecade classifier and use it inplace of frontal face classifier in your code...There you go.. you can detect the side face...

Onr more thing, see the similar question... 
[See similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886223/detect-face-side-using-opencv)....

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: All these links are dead. You should consider to upgrade them.